# Limit of this recursive sequence: $x_{n+1}=\bigl(1-\frac{1}{2n}\bigr)x_{n}+\frac{1}{2n}x_{n-1}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following sequence :

$x_{0}=a$ , $x_{1}=b$ ,  $x_{n+1}=\bigl(1-\frac{1}{2n}\bigr)x_{n}+\frac{1}{2n}x_{n-1}.$
Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}.$

I calculate $x_{2}$ , $x_{3}$ ,$x_{4}$ ,but I could not find any relationship  between any two consecutive pair. But I found that the sum of the coefficients of $a$ & $b$ is equal to the term in denominator in each $x_{i}$.

How we find this limit...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=-\dfrac{1}{2n}(x_{n}-x_{n-1})$$
so
$$x_{n+1}-x_{n}=(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{2^n\cdot n!}(x_{1}-x_{0})$$
so
$$x_{n}-x_{0}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=a+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n\cdot n!}(b-a)=a+e^{-1/2}(b-a)$$

Comment: "Hint"? Or the hint is that the "hint" is in fact *not* a hint? :) Fine *complete* answer. +1

Comment: 3rd line is not clear to me. please clear it

Comment: @Panja.S. Right side there is a telescopic series: open it up and see what you get!