# Non-autonomous linear difference inequation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a positive sequence.

Suppose that for all $n\geq 1$

$$
a_{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{n}a_n + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)a_{n-1}.
$$
How to study the convergence of $(a_n)$ ? I suppose it converges, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: **Hint:**

perhaps this helps, I'm not sure
$$
a_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n}a_n + (1-\frac{1}{n})a_{n-1} \\
\implies a_{n+1} - a_n \le \frac{1}{n}a_n + (1-\frac{1}{n})a_{n-1} -a_n \\
\implies a_{n+1} - a_n \le -(1-\frac{1}{n})a_n + (1-\frac{1}{n})a_{n-1} \\
\implies a_{n+1} - a_n \le (1-\frac{1}{n})(-a_n + a_{n-1}) \\
$$

Comment: Yes, I have this implication, but don't know how to use it because $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ has no constant sign.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109254

Comment: @cs89: not at all - it's an *inequality* here.

Answer (score 4):

The given inequality gives us that $a_{n+1}\in(0,\max(a_{n},a_{n-1})]$, since it's at most a weighted average of $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$, and because $(a_n)$ is a positive sequence. Then, from Physor's comment, we have that $$a_{n+1}-a_n\le-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)(a_n-a_{n-1})$$ so if the sequence ever increases, then it must next decrease.

Let $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the subsequence such that $a_{n_k}-a_{n_k-1}>0$. If this were a finite sequence, then we would be done: $(a_n)$ is bounded below by $0$, and if it's decreasing after a point, so then it must converge to a limit. Assume then that $(a_{n_k})$ is an infinite sequence. These set the maximums for further $a_n$. That is, if $n\ge n_k$ for some $k$, then $a_n\le a_{n_k}$. We first want to show that $a_{n_k}$ converges, and for this, it's enough to show that it's decreasing. This is true because it can never increase after hitting a relative maximum. That is, $a_{n+1}\le\max(a_n,a_{n-1})$ applied recursively implies $a_m\le \max(a_n,a_{n-1})$ for $m\ge n+1$. In particular, this means that $a_{n_{k+1}}\le \max(a_{n_k},a_{n_k-1})=a_{n_k}$ since $n_{k+1}\ge n_k+1$.

So $a_{n_k}$ converges to a limit $L$. From the construction of $a_{n_k}$, this is $\limsup a_n$. Similarly, $\liminf a_n=\lim a_{n_k-1}$, so it suffices to show that $a_{n_k-1}$ converges and converges to the same limit.

We also know that $a_{n_k-2}\ge a_{n_k-1}$ and $a_{n_k-1}< a_{n_k}$. And since $a_m\le\max(a_n,a_{n-1})$ for $m\ge n+1$, we have that $a_{n_{k+1}}\le\max(a_{n_k-1},a_{n_k-2})=a_{n_k-2}$ where I used the fact that $a_{n_k-2}\ge a_{n_k-1}$ since the sequence can't increase twice in a row. This means that $\liminf a_{n_k-2}\ge L$, and since $L=\limsup a_n$, this means that $\liminf a_{n_k-2}=L$.

Then $$a_{n_k}\le \frac{1}{n_k-1}a_{n_k-1}+\left(1-\frac{1}{n_k-1}\right)a_{n_k-2}$$ gives us that $$(n_k-1)a_{n_k}-\left(n_k-2\right)a_{n_k-2}\le a_{n_k-1}$$

We know that $a_{n_k}$ and $a_{n_k-2}$ converge to the same limit, which implies that $a_{n_k-1}$ has that same limit as a lower bound (to be more rigorous, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k\ge K$, $L-\epsilon<a_{n_k-1}$). Thus, $\liminf a_{n_k-1}=\liminf a_n\ge L=\limsup a_n$, which means that $\lim a_n$ exists and equals $L$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, $a_n \leq a_1$, $a_{n-1} \leq a_1$ we have that $a_{n+1} \leq a_1$.

Since $a_2 \leq a_1$ assuming $a_0 = 0$, we have that $a_n \leq a_1$ for all $n$.

Hence the sequence is bounded above by $a_1$ and bounded below by $0$, hence has a convergent subsequence.

An unwrapped upper bound:

Since $a_2 \leq a_1$, Let $a_2 = \frac{a_1(b_1+b_2)}{2}$ for some $b_1,b_2 >0$.

Then by induction for $n \geq 4$,
$$a_n \leq \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + a_1 (b_1 + b_2)}{n-1}$$
Hence,
$$a_n \leq \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + 2a_2}{n-1}$$

Hence the sequence is upper bounded by its caesaro mean with $a_1$ replaced by $a_2$ in caesaro mean.

This implies:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n} a_i + 2a_2}{n} \leq \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + 2a_2}{n-1}$$
This implies that Cèsaro mean is a decreasing sequence and since its bounded below by $0$, Cèsaro mean converges to a limit $\ell_{Cèsaro \ mean}$.

Let $a_{\ell_k} \rightarrow \limsup_m a_m$ then since $$a_n \leq \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + 2a_2}{n-1} \implies $$

$$a_{\ell_k} \leq \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{\ell_k-1} a_i + 2a_2}{\ell_k-1} \leq \limsup_m a_m $$

Hence,
$$\ell_{Cèsaro \ mean} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + 2a_2}{n-1} = \limsup_n \frac{\sum_{i=3}^{n-1} a_i + 2a_2}{n-1} = \limsup_m a_m$$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the recurrence

$$
a_{n+1}- \frac{1}{n}a_n - \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)a_{n-1}+s_n^2=0
$$

we have

$$
(a_{n+1}-a_n) + (a_n - a_{n-1}) -\frac 1n(a_n-a_{n-1})+s_n^2=0
$$

now calling $b_n = a_n-a_{n-1}$ we follow with

$$
b_{n+1}+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)b_n + s_n^2 = 0
$$

with solution

$$
b_n = \frac 1n\left((-1)^{n}c_0+\sum_k(-1)^{n-k}k s_k^2\right)
$$

Here, as $s_k$ are any, we can choose them such that

$$
\sum_k(-1)^{n-k}k s_k^2 = -\sigma_n^2
$$

and we follow with

$$
a_n-a_{n-1} = \frac 1n\left((-1)^{n}c_0-\sigma_n^2\right)
$$

or

$$
a_n - a_{n-1}\le \frac 1n(-1)^{n}c_0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the version of the recurrence that enforces equality will converge to a specific number. Let $a_n=\beta_n a_1+(1-\beta_n) a_2$ (where $\beta_1=1$ and $\beta_2=0$). In this situation, we could write
$$
\beta_{n+1}a_1+(1-\beta_{n+1})a_2=\frac1n(\beta_na_1+(1-\beta_n)a_2)+\left(1-\frac1n\right)(\beta_{n-1}a_1+(1-\beta_{n-1})a_2)
$$
which simplifies down to
$$
\beta_{n+1}=\frac1n\beta_n+\left(1-\frac1n\right)\beta_{n-1}
$$
such that $\beta_1=1$ and $\beta_2=0$.

Let's investigate the impact of going "less than" on a single step. Let's say that, when calculating $a_{n+1}$, we reduce the value by $\delta_{n+1}>0$. Now, what we have is
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\beta_na_1+(1-\beta_n)a_2\\
a_{n+1}&=\beta_{n+1}a_1+(1-\beta_{n+1})a_2-\delta_{n+1}
\end{align}$$
The assertion I will make here is that this effectively changes the $a_1$ and $a_2$ values. Let's assume
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\beta_n\hat a_1+(1-\beta_n)\hat a_2\\
a_{n+1}&=\beta_{n+1}\hat a_1+(1-\beta_{n+1})\hat a_2
\end{align}$$
From this, we can determine that
$$
\pmatrix{\beta_n&1-\beta_n\\\beta_{n+1}&1-\beta_{n+1}}\pmatrix{a_1-\hat a_1\\a_2-\hat a_2}=\pmatrix{0\\\delta_{n+1}}
$$
or
$$\begin{align}
\hat a_1&=a_1 + \frac{1-\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}\delta_{n+1}\\
\hat a_2&=a_2 - \frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}\delta_{n+1}
\end{align}$$
Of course, we really care about where it's going, rather than where it currently is or where it began. So let's use the fact that, if we assume equality to infinity from here, then we have
$$
\lim a_n = Ba_1+(1-B)a_2
$$
where $B\approx0.30685$. Therefore, with the updates, we have
$$\begin{align}
\lim \hat a_n &= B\hat a_1+(1-B)\hat a_2\\
&= \lim a_n + B\frac{1-\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}\delta_{n+1}-(1-B)\frac{\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}\delta_{n+1}\\
&= \lim a_n + \frac{B-\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}\delta_{n+1}
\end{align}$$
We're nearly where we need to be. We now turn our attention to the number multiplying $\delta_{n+1}$. Let's call it $c_n=\frac{B-\beta_n}{\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}}$. Now, we know that $\beta_n$ converges to $B$, and by observation that $\beta_{n+1}$ is between $\beta_n$ and $\beta_{n-1}$, we can also determine that $\beta_n-\beta_{n+1}$ alternates sign. What's more, because $B$ must always be between $\beta_n$ and $\beta_{n+1}$ for a similar reason, $B-\beta_n$ must also alternate sign. Therefore, $c_n$ must keep its sign for all $n$ - it must always be positive, or always be negative.

But $c_1=B-1<0$. Therefore, $c_n<0$ for all $n$, and $\lim \hat a_n < \lim a_n$ (because $c_n<0$ and $\delta_n>0$).

This must occur each time that the value of $a_{n+1}$ is less than, rather than equal to, the RHS, and therefore the limit must decrease every time. Since the change to the limit must necessarily be negative, we conclude that the sequence must converge to a value smaller than $Ba_1+(1-B)a_2$, given that there is a minimum possible value.